# Lottie Animations JSON Animation file not found exception Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android for this work and I have placed my testanim.json file in assets folder. When I run the app it always throws error File not found exception below is my XML code for Lottie Animation

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My C# code is as follows:

```
LottieAnimationView animationView = FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.animation_view);
animationView.SetAnimation("testanim.json");
animationView.Loop(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution finally:

**Problem:**
yourfile.json animation file in assets folder had Build Action set to None.

**Solution:**
Right click on yourfile.json animation file and go to properties and set the Build Action to AndroidAssets. Now build and see your animation in project.

**Note:** If you have added file into Resources/raw folder then go to json file properties and set the Build Action to AndroidResrouce and I have used below given code to reference animation from Resource/raw

```
animationView.SetAnimation(Resource.Raw.animationFile);
```

**Remember:** Do not use the '-' in your animation file name instead use '_'.